# GTM, Prestashop and Smarty {literal}

Tags: javascript, smarty, prestashop, google-tag-manager

I want to add a dataLayer for GTM in my order-confirmation page on Prestashop.
So like it's precise in the Smarty documentation I use `{literal}`, `{ldelim}` and `{rdelim}`.

My script need to be dynamic for send the correct data to GTM, depends on the commande the client just passed.

I modify the header.tpl file since I need to put the JS before the GTM tag.

Here my code :

```
{if isset($page_name) && $page_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8' == "order-confirmation"}
    {literal}
        <script>
    {/literal}
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
        dataLayer.push({ldelim}
           'transactionId': '{$id_order}',
           'transactionTotal': {$total_paid_tax_incl},
           'transactionProducts': [
           {foreach from=$products item=product}
               {ldelim}                            // List of productFieldObjects.
                   'sku': '{$product.id}',
                   'name': '{$product.name}',     // Name or ID is required.
                   //'category': '{$product.X}',
                   'price': {$product.price},
                   'quantity': 1                        // Optional fields may be omitted or set to empty string.
               {rdelim}{if !$smarty.foreach.product.last},{/if}
           {/foreach}
        ]
        {rdelim});
    {literal}
        </script>
    {/literal}
{/if}
```

The result is nothing is displayed... BUT if I remove the

```
{literal}<script>{/literal}
```

and the

```
{literal}</script>{/literal}
```

part, the JS is displaying fine, but of course outside a

`<script>...</script>`...

Thanks for the help,

Perceval

Answer (score 1):

I'll made for you some little corrections:

```
{if isset($page_name) && $page_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8' == "order-confirmation"}
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
        dataLayer.push({ldelim}
           'transactionId': '{$id_order}',
           'transactionTotal': {$total_paid_tax_incl},
           'transactionProducts': [
           {foreach from=$products item=product}
               {ldelim}                            
               // List of productFieldObjects.
                   'sku': '{$product.id}',
                   'name': '{$product.name}',     // Name or ID is required.
                   //'category': '{$product.X}',
                   'price': {$product.price},
                   'quantity': 1                        // Optional fields may be omitted or set to empty string.
               {rdelim}
               {if !$smarty.foreach.product.last},{/if}
           {/foreach}
        ]
        {rdelim});
        </script>
{/if}
```

It's always tricky to mesh up smarty code with js, in your case I don't suggest the use of `{literal}` tag, try and let me know ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've tried your code, but it's not working... Smarty make me crazy ><'